# OPENQUERY update on linked server

Tags: sql, sql-update, linked-server, openquery

I want to execute the following statement through from a linked server (openquery):

```
UPDATE SAP_PLANT 
SET (OWNER, OWNER_COUNTRY) = (SELECT import.AFNAME, import.COUNTRY
                                FROM SAP_IMPORT_CUSTOMERS import, SAP_PLANT plant
                                WHERE plant.SAP_FL = import.SAP_NO
                                AND import.role ='OWNER')
```

I've tried to form it into the following syntax, without success :(

```
update openquery(‘my_linked_server, ‘select column_1, column_2 from table_schema.table_name where pk = pk_value’)
set column_1 = ‘my_value1′, column_2 = ‘my_value2′
```

I hope for you this is no problem?

Comment: Have you tried using fully-qualified names for the remote table(s) in the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is not really a query you want to open, rather an SQL statement you want to execute. So instead of openquery, you shoud use execute. See example G here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx

So your script shoul look like

```
execute ('your sql command here') at my_linked_server
```

Comment: NOTE: Ensure `RPC Out` is set to `True` on the Linked Server properties.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting syntax error?  Your server parameter in the `update openquery` is missing a trailing quote.  Change ```my_linked_server`to`my_linked_server'`.